# Angular number pipe doesn't work in a modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I get an error - Error: NG0302: The pipe 'number' could not be found!  when I used it in a modal of my Ionic Framework Angular app.  The code below works fine in the parent page and other places in the app without any pipe declarations. It just fails in the modal.

```
{{ data.amount | number: '1.2-2'}}
```

I even tried the following to see if I can somehow convert my amount to two decimal places or may be put through a pipe but no success.

```
{{ data.amount*1.00 }}
```

Comment: Mind sharing your file-structure regarding the parentpage and modal? Also each .module files? To me it sounds like you havent imported the pipe in the correct module.

Comment: The number pipe comes with the angular core.  Your argument would be valid if it were a custom pipe.  -  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

Comment: That's not entirely true as you still need to make the modules known to the component for it to work. If you want to use the built in forms / reactive-forms module from @angular/forms you very much need it to be imported in the module for the component to be able to use it.

Comment: The DecimalPipe (number) is in the CommonMudule. If you Modal is in its own module you need to import it there.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen - Yes I have it imported in my module of the modal - import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much simpler and easier workaround for this -

In my page.ts file - I got the amount value from the array and used the javascript toFixed function to convert my amount to 2 decimals.  This is not ideal but it works.  To use the angular way, it required importing and declaring DecimalPipe at so many places.

```
 this.amount = this.amount.toFixed(2);
```

Angular 1.0 used to be so simple to use.  After that it has become a bag of frustrations.  Next app in React for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Without really knowing your file-structure I think the following is happening, correct me if im wrong:

```
Pages-folder
- parent-page-folder
  - parent.page.html
  - parent.page.ts
  - parent.page.scss
  - parent.module.ts
  - parent-routing.module.ts
  - modal-component-folder
    - modal.component.ts
    - modal.component.html
    - modal.component.scss
```

As you can see by this structure your modal.component does not have a module and thus do not have the necessary imports to use any built in functions from angular. What you can do is create a modal.module.ts and import the modules needed. it could look like this:

Parent-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ParentPageRoutingModule } from './parent-routing.module';

import { ParentPage } from './parent.page';
import { ModalModule } from './modal/modal.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ModalModule, // <-- needs to be declared in parent module 
    ParentPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ParentPage]
})
export class ParentPageModule {}
```

and the manually created modal-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule],
  declarations: [ModalComponent]
})
export class ModalModule {}
```

Hopefully this gives you some insight in how you make different functionalities known to components in angular, even if they are built in.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  My code looks exactly like yours.  The only difference is that instead of a component, my modal is a page that is at the same level as the parent page.  Modal invokes fine and shows all the relevant data.  The only issue is cannot use the number pipe.  I even imported the module into the parent page but it didn't work.

Comment: I see, well it would be easier to deduce the issue if you are able to share the file structure but seeing as you found a workaround for the problem i take it as this being solved.